# Отображение системной информации в виде графиков

Tags: javascript, диаграммы

Добрый день!
Подскажите какие нибудь либы на JS для рисования графиков, подходящие для мониторинга в реалтайме, т.е. туда должно влезать ОЧЕНЬ много данных.
загрузка CPU, различные типы памяти, пакеты и скорость с разных источников, желательно с отображением параметров среднего, максимального и т.д. значений.
Всего будет порядка 10-20 параметров.
Т.е. должно быть что-то вроде такого, как на изображении, но более современное и функциональное.

Обычный Chart.js или Highcharts, не подойдут.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете написать свои, для этого можно воспользоваться библиотекой D3, поддерживает `svg`, `canvas`, `webgl`.

Ссылки: 
[Оф. сайт](https://d3js.org/)
[Примеры](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery)